# why AWS ec2 instance Inodes getting increase autometically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am a person who has basic knowledge of AWS EC2 instances. I have created an EC2 instance on AWS its t2 micro instance with the volume of 8GB so everything was working completely fine.but suddenly I got an error when I was trying to fire `touch` or `mkdir` commands it was showing me an error which is: **no space left on device** so I had gone in the ec2 console and attached 8 GB volume to my instance.After attaching volume everything was working again fine.but inodes getting full within some hours.I am not able to figure out the problem.Below I have attached screenshot you can see in the screenshot.[image]

as you can see I have connected instance between the gap of some time. when I connected the first time it was 83%. but when I connected after some time it is showing 88%. now it will be going to full after 1 or 2 hours.And my site will be stopped working. Please, anyone, have an idea how to overcome this problem.I will be really appreciated

Comment: Something is eating up disk space fairly quickly.  You need to figure that out first. At a guess it is something related to logging but it may be something else.  What is your tech stack?

Comment: @stdunbar how do i  figure out that what is eating up disk space.